# Proving the existence of a Markov Chain via Kolomogorov extension theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I want to show given a countable state space $E$, a stochastic matrix $P:E\times E\to [0,1]$ and an initial distribution $a: E\to [0,1]$, there exists an $E$-valued Markov Chain $(X_{n})_{n\in \mathbb N_{0}}$ on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb P)$ with intial distribution $a$ and transition matrix $P$.

Our definition of a Markov chain:

$(X_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N_{0}}$ is an $E$-valued  Markov chain on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb P)$ with transition matrix $P$ and initial distribution $a$ if and only if we have

$\mathbb P(X_{n+1}=x_{n+1}\lvert X_{n}=x_{n},...., X_{0}=x_{0})=P(x_{n},x_{n+1})$ and $\mathbb P(X_{0}=x_{0})=a(x_{0})$.

I want to specifically prove the existence of a Markov Chain via the Kolomogorov extension theorem:

Note that I want to characterize the $P_{J}$ which are probability measures on $(E^{J},\mathcal{B}(E)^{J})$ in the following way, for $\{x_{j}\}_{j \in J}\in \mathcal{B}(E)^{J}$ we have:

$P_{J}(\{x_{j}\}_{j \in J})=a(x_{0})P(x_{0},x_{1})...P(x_{n-1},x_{n})\; (*)$

for $J \subseteq \mathbb N_{0}$ finite. Of course I can adjust $(*)$ in case $J$ does not have "adjacent entries starting from $0$" by summing over the missing components.

Now I need to show that $(P_{J})_{J\subseteq \mathbb N_{0},\text{ finite}}$ is indeed a projective/consistent family of probability measures, i.e. for $J\subseteq H\subseteq \mathbb N_{0}$ where both subsets are finite we have $P_{H}\circ (p_{H}^{J})^{-1}=P_{J}$ where $p_{H}^{J}:(E^{H},\mathcal{B}(E)^{H})\to (E^{J},\mathcal{B}(E)^{J})$ is the measurable projection map.

Any idea on how to go about this?